# how to deploy a docker container using kubernetes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, docker

Currently I have created a ubuntu 14.04 docker image by pulling it off from the dockerhub website and did a docker run on this image to create a container instance of this image.Then I installed apache server inside this running container and ran the server from this container.

Now how do I deploy this docker container using kubernetes??

Comment: Please edit your existing question about this subject (which is extremely similar to this one) rather than re-asking about your problem. Tell us what exactly you have tried – sharing your research is important when asking a question here. How to deploy a Docker container using Kubernetes is described in lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Normally:

1. Your docker image doesn't need to run Apache, just the server code (for instance, tomcat, springboot or else). A good deal of what was done by Apache is done by the K8S infrastructure. In the few cases where an Apache is necessary (to serve static content for instance), it can be another container in the same "pod" as your server container.
2. To create an image you don't do a `docker run`, you create a Dockerfile and do a proper `docker build`.
3. Kubernetes (aka K8S) isn't a deployment utility, it is an infrastructure to run and monitor containers. The deployment is only a small part of it.

   - If you haven't got that infrastructure running you have to build one. For a single container it is an overkill(*). You can look at `docker-compose` for simple deployments. Many things you do with `docker-compose` can later be translated to K8S. To run some containers in a Linux image you just create a systemd service that starts them.
   - If you have a K8S infrastructure you can deploy containers/pods through the console as a first step, and then learn to use `kubectl`. But the people who created that infrastructure can likely help (and will have their own deployment standards).

(*) and given your apparent current Docker skills this is going to be quite difficult. It has to be properly done to work (and not be hacked through in its first days of existence).

Comment: Please first direct the user to ask a good question on the Stack Exchange network instead of giving him answers to a vague problem. Seeing that you've [answered a previous question of his](https://superuser.com/a/1415968/48078), for which you haven't received any feedback or comments, I'd recommend to first get the OP to give you more information about what he *actually* wants to do, what he already knows, and where he got stuck.